# Diagrams not drawing on QGIS

Tags: qgis, diagram

I'm trying to draw a pie chart on QGIS, over a polygon layer. This pie chart should include data from 6 fields in the attribute table. These fields contain the percentage of several categories of data and all of them sum up to 100% (I've checked it personally). However, the diagrams option in layer properties gives no result. Anyone knows what may be going on?

Comment: I believe I have found a workaround - creating centroids for the polygons. I had previously checked the geometry of the polygons and there were no errors detected, so that did not seem to be the problem.

Apparently, this function only works with point layers. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Cannot confirm your comment. Diagrams DO work for polygon layers just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try turning off simplification for the layer, under the rendering tab. That might be causing invalid geometries which prevent the diagrams from being placed correctly.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked fine - seemingly, that was exactly what was preventing the diagrams from being drawn.